# What does Unity's "Speed of Sound"-option do?

Tags: unity, audio, configuration

I've been reading Unity's manual on [the `AudioManager`'s properties](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-AudioManager.html).  *Speed of Sound* is the only undocumented option. What is it for?

Comment: lol just based on the title I was like "...what does this have to do with game development" but I see this is actually a good question

Comment: Now that I think about it, it sure looks like if I were trolling a moderator: that sudden urge to press the flag stops when you read the body. lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like this value is a measure of the *physical speed of sound*, and likely plays a part in the result of the simulation of the [Doppler effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect) (if enabled).

The value shown in the screenshot in the documentation is 347, which is very close to the actual [speed of sound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound) (343 meters-per-second at sea level).

It doesn't appear to have anything to do with the observed *playback speed* of the sound.